# Maps, Facebook, Email, Youtube Errors in Android Eclipse Simulator

Tags: android, eclipse, simulator

I am getting the errors within the simulator (1.6 version) when I click and try and access the information.

I have created a screen capture of all the errors in the simulator.

[image: Go to: www.goinggreenfilmfestival.com/errors-simulator.jpg]

I looked into some of the coding and a lot of the features say:

```
//showLocationMap 
public void showLocationMap(){
```

It looks like a lot of the features say void. Maybe that is the issue? So how do I change that so that the feature is allowed?

Comment: FYI:  I created the project from www.buzztouch.com, then loaded into the Simulator with Eclipse.  I am not a programmer.  First app I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You must download and install the gapps and arm translation in your simulator or try to download and install the gennymotion for android simulators and install the gapps in your simulator. see the link 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952